# Colorize table rows depending of

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to colorize (css style #) with different color each table rows fetched from this query:

`SELECT * FROM cars GROUP BY engine ORDER BY brand...`

//echo (golf, ford, golf, audi, golf, fiat, audi...)

For example, all rows with Golf brand paint red, green Audi, etc.
Please help. Tnx!

Comment: Try writing something yourself and then when it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along.  You start it, we help.  We don't write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `class='[brand]'` to each row, where `[brand]` would be the brand eg. `class='golf'`. You could then style it via your css-file.

```
.golf { color:red }
```

Comment: Tnx for replay...The problem is that I do not know in advance what types of cars brand we have in the database (there can be a lot)

Answer (score 0):

There's many ways to do this.

Assuming that you are using a loop to output your rows, you would pass the `id` by identifying the `make` of the car:

```
 foreach($row as $r){
     echo '<div id="'.$r['make'].'">...</div>';
 }
```

Then in your `CSS` just style accordingly.

Comment: Tnx for replay...The problem is that I do not know in advance what types of cars brand we have in the database (there can be a lot)

Comment: The color needs to be predetermined, unless you build a mechanism that assigns colors on-the-fly.

Comment: There is no PHP function that lets you do this, however way you try to do this, you will have to enter in the `CSS` yourself.

Comment: "assigns colors on-the-fly"<br>that's it...i suppose that for function that could be done

Answer (score 0):

What about making your php script generate the css script that will put color into each table rows ? Then you also generate css class names accordingly in your markup.